# Receive Files using teraterm ZMODEM

Tags: serial-port, teraterm, zmodem

I'm using teraterm from my windows PC.

I have a serial (USB) port conection to a board that is running linux.

I have access to the linux terminal throught teraterm.

**This is the only way to interact with the board.**

I want to "copy" files from the board in my PC. For this I thought on using the ZMODEM/receive option.

When I choose the ZMODEM/send option I achieve to send files from my PC to the board, so I asume I have the rigth configuration.

However when I choose the ZMODEM/receive nothing happens, I cannot write the file's name. I think teraterm is waiting for the board to send it.

Is there a way to specify the filename from my PC and receiving it without "manipulating" the board?

- I can run sh scripts on the board, but I should not install new software in it.
- I'm open to other solutions with teraterm (maybe ZMODEM is not the right way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it.

I had to use the `sz` command on linux.

So, on the board I launched:

```
sz /my/file/name.wow
```

and then click on transfer>ZMODEM>receive and the transfer started automatically :)

I was used to work with ethernet/ssh and just noticed this method taking a lot more time.